# How get list dns proxy c#

Tags: c#, dns

Can you help me, how to get the dns list from the proxy?

For example, in firefox go to `settings - advanced-network - settings` and there tick `"Proxy dns when using socks 5"` if this checkbox is activated, then when I go to the site whoer.com I see the list of DNS of this proxy.

Is it possible to get this list without using the browser? Using `c#`

If I am not correct in this matter, then please correct me

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the method used by web sites requires a custom DNS server and javascript executed in the browser.

Also, proxy settings vary by application - you say in C# but for what application? Firefox? Chrome? IE? Another application?

Comment: I would like not to use third-party applications, but if no other way then ie (standart webbrowser) or selenium webdriver (firefox)